# How do I Select or Place data from multiple rows into a single row or column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am not even sure how to ask this question:

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I want to select the colors by either using either an Alias or maybe re-insert? 
Not sure but I need it to look like this.

[image]

How can I pull this off?

Thank you so much.

***Update: This is for SQL Server 2012***

Comment: have you tried search on SO? I think it's most popular SQL question ever!

Comment: This is for SQL Server: I am familiar with Pivoting and CTE/Sub Queries and all that stuff. I am not even sure what to search for.

Comment: What RDBMS? SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server

```
select
    C.UserID,
    stuff(
        (
            select ', ' + t.Color
            from table1 as t
            where t.UserID = C.UserID
            order by t.Color
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 2, '')
from table1 as C
group by C.UserID
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d18e/7)

Comment: Thank you so much! That Fiddle Is so cool. Did not know such a thing existed. Thanks again. You code/example is extremely helpful.